# Custom New Web Part Page Template when creating page

Tags: web-part-zone, web-part, page-layout, master-page

I want to give the user the ability to create web part pages, from a template, where the the left column is a web part, lets call it LEFTNAVPART, and the header is another web part, let's call it TOPNAVPART. When the user is creating a new web part page, the template will already have LEFTNAVPART and TOPNAVPART already on the page. They will be able to add a web part(s) for the body once the page is created, let's call it BODYNAVPART(s).

In use once the page is set up, when the user:
1. clicks on LEFTNAVPART, TOPNAVPART and BODYNAVPART will be updated.
2. clicks on TOPNAVPART, LEFTNAVPART and BODYNAVPART will be updated.
3. clicks on BODYNAVPART, other BODYNAVPARTs may be updated.

It doesn't seem like a master page will do this, since all pages on a site are affected by the master page. Is there a way this can be done in SharePoint or do I have to have the user add the LEFTNAVPART and TOPNAVPART web parts as well? If no, is there another way to get this desired behavior?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way this could be done is customizing a site using SharePoint designer to have the webparts where you want them.  Then you can save that site as a template.

I could be wrong but I don't think you'll be able to use webpart connections for this sicne you are creating it from a template, you might have to come up with some other way for the webparts to talk to one another.  Maybe through querystring or page viewstate?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look in to Page Layouts if you are wanting this page to be used in multiple locations. Then, as Steve said, you could use web part connections (if necessary), query strings, and other ways of passing data to the other web parts.